# Success handler for ko.applyBindings

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a piece of code that is to be executed after applyBindings is done successfully.

```
var vmObject = new myViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vmObject, document.getElementById('page1'));
dependantMethod();
```

Because of asynchronous execution, sometimes dependantMethod() is executed sooner. Is there a way to find out whether ko.applyBindings has been successfully executed, so that I can put dependantMethod(); inside the success handler?

Thanks.

Comment: `applyBindings` isn't asynchronous, so in your code example `dependantMethod` is always executed after `applyBindings` has succesfully been executed. `applyBindings` might trigger something asynchronous though, but we need to see your `myViewModel` code for that.

Comment: can you close/delete the question depending on the outcome your end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your viewmodel it's difficult to answer fully, but you may want to consider using the [knockout subscribe](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html) function within your view model.

If you have an observable or observable array in your viewmodel, you can subscribe to changes to it and validated it has expected values and call your dependant function from there.

```
var myViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.myArray = ko.observableArray([]);

    // some code that populates the array

    var subscription = self.myArray.subscribe(function (arr) {
        // some check on the observable
        if (arr.length > 0) {
            self.dependantMethod();                                
        }
    });

    self.dependantMethod = function () {
        // execute your code

        // posibly dispose of the subscription if you don't want 
        // it called multiple times
        subscription.dispose(); 
    };
}
```